# In the notification function Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages, can we call a js function on click of the hyper link

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Is there a way to call a function on-click on the hyperlink in the message notification from listener addin-ins in outlook

```
    Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages.replaceAsync("action", criteriaChangeMessage);
```

I'm trying to call a js function, when clicked on the hyperlink msg `Show Addin`. I tried with the callback, but it gets called irrespective of whether the msg or link is clicked on not.
Thanks.

below is the code snippet

```
var criteriaChangeMessage = {
      type: Office.MailboxEnums.ItemNotificationMessageType.InsightMessage,
      message: "There is a change in the meeting criteria.",
      icon: "Icon.80x80",   
      actions: [
        {
          actionText: "Show Addin",
          actionType: Office.MailboxEnums.ActionType.ShowTaskPane, //"showTaskPane"
          commandId: "msgReadOpenPaneButton",
          contextData: "{''}",
        },
      ],
    };
    
    Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages.replaceAsync("action", criteriaChangeMessage);
```

Answer (score 0):

InsightMessage Notification is to add the notification with the link to open the taskpane, any other js cannot be run on the click of the button.
Currently the feature is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [Tech Community Page](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions). Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when we go through our planning process.